# Combine variable and string in an array

Tags: powershell

I am trying to combine a variable with a text to return a string within an array but can't seem to be able to get the syntax right.

```
$arrEnvConfig = switch -WildCard ($host) {
    "*MST*" {
        "$envEpicCommFilePath + 'MST-EpicComm.env'", "MST", "$iconPath + 'MST_text.ico'"
    }
    "*TST*" {
        "$envEpicCommFilePath + 'TST-EpicComm.env'", "MST", "$iconPath + 'TST_text.ico'"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular about how to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: May be you should try using `Join-Path` cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this it?  Looks like the comma has a higher precedence than the +.

```
($envEpicCommFilePath + 'MST-EpicComm.env'), 'MST', ($iconPath + 'MST_text.ico')
```

Comment: That works. I did it like that before posting and it did not work. I am now noticing this morning it wasn't working because I changed one of the variables. Since I was working on two different computers I never updated the script. Thank you.